# Chat message window should be extensible

Tags: feature-request, chat, user-interface

When I extend the chat window by clicking the right-down handle to enlarge the window (using Google Chrome), and when I input many lines full of words, the last line cannot be seen.

You see that the handle disappears and I always cannot edit the last line of words.

[image: chat message box]

Can the chat window be extensible by mouse's moving up and down to resize the chat room?

[image]